# Is there any injective parametrization of Klein bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

"Let $K$ be (the topological space that is known to topologists as) the Klein bottle. There's a standard immersion $f:K \to \mathbb{R}^3$, whose image is known, in popular culture, as "the Klein bottle". $f$ is, of course, not an embedding. Is there a continuous injective function defined on a product of intervals, $\sigma:I \times J \to \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $\sigma(I \times J) = f(K)$?''

I think no, because Klein bottle intersects itself. But I think it is not a safe justification, since the cillinder

\begin{cases} 25x^2 - 25y^2 - x^4 - 2x^2y^2 - y^4 = 0 \\ -1 \leq z \leq 1 \end{cases}

(generated by traslating a lemniscate along the $z$ axis) in some way intersects itself, but it is the image of a continuous, injective $\sigma: (-1,1) \times [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$, as indicated in the figure below. I still think my conclusion about the Klein bottle is true, but I wish a better justification for it.

[image: Cillinder]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. There is no subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ homeomorphic to the Klein bottle.

Comment: I did not talk about homeomorphism. An injective, continuous  map is not necessarily an homeomorphism, is it?

Comment: Well, then what do you mean when you say "$\mathrm{im} \sigma$ is a Klein bottle"? It can't be because the Klein bottle is not a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: The injective image of a compact space into a Hausdorff space is the original space.

Comment: @Connor Malin  $I \times J$ is not necessarily compact. Did you see the figure? That sheet is an injective image of $(-1, 1) \times [-1, 1]$ and if we paste together the dashed lines in that position, we will have a different space, although still an injective image of $(-1, 1) \times [-1, 1]$.

Comment: I voted to close because you haven't clarified what you mean by "$\mathrm{im}\,\sigma$ is a Klein bottle."

Comment: Why is it not clear? For me, it means a equality of sets. There is a Klein bottle that is equal to the image of $\sigma$. How I must edit the question?

Comment: Here's a rephrasing: "Let $K$ be (the topological space that is known to topologists as) the Klein bottle. There's a standard immersion $f: K \to \Bbb R^3$, whose image is known, in popular culture, as "the Klein bottle." $f$ is, of course, not an embedding. Is there a continuous injective function defined on a product of intervals, $s: I \times J \to \Bbb R^3$ such that $im(s) = im(f)$, i.e., such that $s(I \times J) = f(K)$?" Does that about capture it?

Comment: By the way, assuming that my rephrasing is correct, the answer (which I'd be happy to write up) is "yes."

Comment: I have edited the question according to the suggestion of @JohnHughes . And I am curious to know why the answer is "yes".

Comment: Well...if it ever gets reopened, I'll write it up. It's basically just your "extruded figure-8" answer applied in a different context.

Comment: Do you agree that the map described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle#Construction is not injective, even if we think of the original square as a product of intervals of the form $[a,b) \times [c,d)$?

Comment: Look at the place where the "tube" crosses the fat surface; the two intersect in a circle, which bounds a disk in the "fat surface". Remove this circle from the "tube" part, but leave it in the "fat surface" (just as in the extruded figure-8 example, you removed the center-line from one sheet but not the other). If you pull back the ends of the tube a tiny but from the surface (again, like your figure-8 example), you'll see that what you've got is a cylinder with two open ends; you can build this from $(-1,1) \times (-\pi, \pi]$ by wrapping: $(x,y) \mapsto (x, \cos y, \sin y)$.

Comment: Then you embed this cylinder-with-two-open ends so that the open ends "almost meet" at the "cut-through" circle of the Klein bottle. [Alas, I cannot draw a picture in the comments.]

Comment: @JohnHughes I think I got it, and I laughed surprised when I realized I was understanding haha. Very good, thank you!

Comment: I voted to reopen now that the question has been clarified to actually make sense.

Comment: @JohnHughes You should give an official answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost I've now done so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, inspired by your "extruded figure 8" example.

Look at the place where the "tube" crosses the fat surface; the two intersect in a circle, which bounds a disk in the "fat surface."
This is the brownish-orange circle in the top-left portion of the figure below. [image: slow modification of Klein bottle into image of product of intervals]

Remove this circle from the "tube" part, but leave it in the "fat surface" (just as in the extruded figure-8 example, you removed the center-line from one sheet but not the other). This results in the second figure: the brown circle remains as part of the main body; the "tube ends" are both "open" (i.e., they look like $S^1 \times (0, ...]$),and I've drawn them dotted. In the next three stages, I've just done some nice homotopies to make this look (in the fourth picture) like $S^1 \times (-1, 1)$. In the fifth picture, I've cut apart the along one of the generating lines, so that in the last picture we have $(-\pi, \pi) \times (-1, 1]$, which is a product of intervals, and we're done.